# Convert text into links with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Detect any URLs in a plain-text and convert em into links, but if its already a link, do nothing.

```
var text = 'text with link <a href="/">www.google.com</a>, another link www.google.com';
```

the result should be:

```
var text = 'text with link <a href="/">www.google.com</a>, another link <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>';
```

Comment: @GopikrishnaS—not really a duplicate, that question is about just URIs in strings, but this question wants to also ignore existing HTML links in text and only convert plain text URIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse with a regexp than looks for urls (search google for examples). Then you need get the index of the string (the located url ) inside de text and make the change (put an "a" attribute arround the link). Then get again other index, until get the EOF.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: This isn't an answer. If you can write a regular expression that will do this reliably and robustly in a general case (i.e. not limited by protocol, port, fragment, query, etc.), then you are able to do something that no one else has been able to do.

Comment: RobG: Maybe is not the best way, but this will work, because simply I'm looking for a string inside a string and then I can append to them every thing I want.